# Django serving from media/ but not static/

Tags: django, static

I had my static files being served form media i.e., the tree looked like this:

media/
/css
/js
/images

with this in my url conf:

```
if settings.SERVE_MEDIA_FROM_DJANGO:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': r'media'}),
    (r'^tiny_mce/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', { 'document_root': r'media/js/tiny_mc' }),
)
```

I then switched it to this:

static/
/css
/js
/images

with this in my url conf:

```
if settings.SERVE_MEDIA_FROM_DJANGO:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': r'static'}),
    (r'^tiny_mce/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', { 'document_root': r'static/js/tiny_mc' }),
)
```

I don't understand why changing media to static has stopped django from serving static files, any ideas?

Cheers,

J

Comment: What django version are you using? If its 1.3 in settings `MEDIA_URL` and `STATIC_URL` can not be set to the same value. Check these values and change them accordingly.

Comment: Here's what I have for MEDIA_URL and STATIC_URL: MEDIA_URL = '/media/' MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media') STATIC_URL = '/static/' STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static') SERVE_MEDIA_FROM_DJANGO = True

Answer (score 1):

Using latest Django? The latest Django only serves the static folder in dev environment. You have to set it up and alias /static to a folder (on Apache) to serve static.

You can find more information about serving static files in Production [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-production).

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the latest and trying to serve with the dev server.

Comment: Here is what fixed it: STATIC_ROOT = '' STATIC_URL = '/static/' STATICFILES_DIRS = (

    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)