# strange django static file behaviour

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, collectstatic

I'm getting 404 for static files when `DEBUG=False` in my settings. The file is served fine when `DEBUG=True`.

I'm looking at the docs and all my configs seem OK to me.

```
# my_settings.py
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/`
```

then I run `collectstatic --settings=my_settings`, and `ls` `static` to confirm it has collected the files. It has:

```
ls ls static/css/core.css
# (its there).
```

But when we request "localhost:8000/static/css/core.css" we get 404.

Note running `python manage.py  findstatic css/core.css --settings=my_settings` fails to find the file. When I do `DEBUG=True` and run `findstatic` it finds the file, but in the sub app's static dir, not the collected directory (`STATIC_ROOT`).

Note I have:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

and "staticfiles" is in my `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Django 1.6

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619464/django-serving-from-media-but-not-static/6619487#6619487 Serving of static files is only enabled by default in development mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have specified `DEBUG = FALSE` in settings, its now left on HTTP server like nginx or apache to serve the static files. You need to configure your webserver to serve static files. An example for apache can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files).